# If I run the Garbage Collector programmatically inside a loop. In does it affect my Android application?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, garbage-collection

To minimize the memory leak problems and optimize my application. I want to make sure the stability of my application and to do this I am looking into the problem of memory allocation and deallocation.

I create an object of data class inside a loop and add it to a list and after that, I don’t need that data class object, so I want to remove that object from the memory without closing the screen or activity.

For this after adding the object to the list, I invoke the System.gc().

Does it affect the application because of too many garbage collection calls?

Comment: It is not recommended to call System.gc() anywhere in ur code especially after a loop. One thing u can do is deallocate that object created after ur use case is done

Comment: GC does not help you in memory leak's use weak reference for storing the object and the store the weak reference in your list

Comment: As far as I know, it does not matter how often you call the GC in your code unless you force it to collect. It basically schedule a task when you call GC, and when the time comes, it will execute GC process. Even though it looks like the best way to reallocate free memory by collecting the unused spaces, GC consumes some processing power to find orphan variables and free-to-reallocate memory spaces.

Comment: After adding Data object to the list , I don't need that object anymore... WRONG. Java passes reference of your object, so after adding data object to the list, you cannot simply mark it up for GC. As long as your list contains a reference to your data object, GC call will not collect it. And also you do not need to manually call GC, it will be called by system and all objects which are not referenced anymore will be collected.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions. my problem with the list is cleared.  But for the knowledge, I just want to ask, If I call the garbage collector randomly does it affect the application. and as @ycansener said it will schedule the garbage collector.  this mean it doesn't call the collectors at the same time, then what will happen to all GC if they invoked at same time?

Comment: `Does it affect the application` yes, it uses CPU time, therefore slows everything down. The other sing is that you should not call GC manually. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector only collects objects which are not referenced in your code anymore. By adding it to a list, a reference is stored in the list and this reference is kept as long as the list is still referenced. If you want GC to collect your object, one of the following things must happen (assuming that neither the object nor the list are referenced anywhere else):

- The object is removed from the list
- The list goes out of scope
- The list variable is set to `null`

In that case, GC will collect the object. In general, the system is pretty smart about when to invoke GC, so invoking GC manually increases the complexity of your program while decreasing its performance (as GC also requires CPU time) and is thus not recommended.

If you wish to avoid memory leaks:

- Make sure there is no stale reference to your objects
- Use `WeakReference`

Answer (score 0):

In comment you asked "what will happen if multiple `gc` calls are invoked at the same time?

> When in doubt, look at the source code.
>
> Source Code of System.gc() method

```
 /**
 * Runs the garbage collector.
 * <p>
 * Calling the <code>gc</code> method suggests that the Java Virtual
 * Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to
 * make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse.
 * When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual
 * Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded
 * objects.
 * <p>
 * The call <code>System.gc()</code> is effectively equivalent to the
 * call:
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * Runtime.getRuntime().gc()
 * </pre></blockquote>
 *
 * @see     java.lang.Runtime#gc()
 */
public static void gc() {
    boolean shouldRunGC;
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        shouldRunGC = justRanFinalization;
        if (shouldRunGC) {
            justRanFinalization = false;
        } else {
            runGC = true;
        }
    }
    if (shouldRunGC) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
}
```

> Declaration of justRanFinalization field.

```
/**
 * If we just ran finalization, we might want to do a GC to free the finalized objects.
 * This lets us do gc/runFinlization/gc sequences but prevents back to back System.gc().
 */
private static boolean justRanFinalization;
```

So if `justRanFinalization` is `false`, then by calling `gc` multiple times you are creating a `boolean` and needlessly acquiring a `LOCK`.

Answer (score -1):

To make your app really responsive do the following.

- Follow the design pattern principle as you need.
- Create good architecture for your project.
- Handling bitmap properly - when not in use do not forget to call recycle() on bitmap, that will cause memory issue.
- Using componentcallback2 we can get memory info in service/activity before doing intensive process.
- Avoid bg service in application. If it is mandatory concentrate on efficient way of handling or use Job Scheduler or intent service.The drawback in service is the RAM(memory) used by a service in not available to another process.
- Instead of using hashmap we can use sparseArray, sparseBooleanArray.
- Do not create local variable in onDraw method().
- Remove memory intensive resources and dependencies.
- Reduce overall size of a apk.
- Use dagger2 for dependency injection, it does not use reflection api, but other library uses reflection api they gives noticeable delay while running the app.
- It’s recommended creating all your layout using xml file. It’s better you do this with Coordinator layout.
- Do all your time consuming process off the main thread.
- When loading multiple images parallely over network call do it with caching mechanism.

Still you want to initiate garbage collection manually you can do it, but not recommended instead kill your app and sleep.